# Diagnoising a hardware issue on linux

Tags: gentoo, hardware, laptop, crash

I have a laptop that completly turns its self off after an unpredictable amount of time. It also doesn't allow for its self to turn it back on after a period of time.

To me this sounds like an issue with heat. However, I've tried to max out the heat by running multiple instances of Glspheres. [which got the temperature from 50c to 90c. Still no problems, the fans did turn on. The HD is new, an SSD, and it passed SMART.

The /var/log/messages only contain these messages before the crash:

```
ul 20 23:08:49 ai logger: ACPI event unhandled: thermal_zone TZ0 00000081 00000000
Jul 20 23:08:49 ai logger: ACPI event unhandled: processor CPU0 00000081 00000000
Jul 20 23:08:49 ai logger: ACPI event unhandled: processor CPU1 00000081 00000000
Jul 20 23:08:49 ai logger: ACPI event unhandled: processor CPU2 00000081 00000000
Jul 20 23:08:49 ai logger: ACPI event unhandled: processor CPU3 00000081 00000000
Jul 20 23:08:49 ai logger: ACPI event unhandled: processor CPU4 00000081 00000000
Jul 20 23:08:50 ai logger: ACPI event unhandled: processor CPU5 00000081 00000000
Jul 20 23:08:50 ai logger: ACPI event unhandled: processor CPU6 00000081 00000000
Jul 20 23:08:50 ai logger: ACPI event unhandled: processor CPU7 00000081 00000000
```

However they are not consistant with completely crashing.

So my question is:

Is there a way to do a diagnosis on the hardware with linux?

I'm using Gentoo, but that won't prevent me from using other tools.

Comment: 90C is not problematic for a GPU, but would be for a CPU. Most CPUs will shut off around 100-110C while some GPUs are rated has high as 140C. Run CPU intensive applications rather than GPU intensive.

Comment: Any suggestions on what would be cpu intensive? Its an i7 btw.

Comment: `yes | xargs -n 1 -P 8 md5sum /dev/urandom`. Replace 8 with the number of cores.